# Tkinter program consumes all RAM/CPU

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I ran this code and the RAM in my computer with my processor looks like it's going to explode! What is the reason?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import os

bloque1=Tk()

bloque1.title('Bloque1')
bloque1.config(bg="#1C1C1C")
bloque1.geometry("450x410")


barramenu=Menu(bloque1)
menubar=Menu(bloque1)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Actividades", menu=menubar)
menubar.add_command(label="Instrucciones")
menubar.add_command(label="Ayuda")
menubar.add_command(label="Cerrar", command=bloque1.quit)
bloque1.config(menu=menubar)


bloque1.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to attach a menu to itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a menu to itself. No doubt this is causing an infinite loop inside of Tkinter.

```
menubar.add_cascade(label="Actividades", menu=menubar)
```

That `menu=` attribute needs to be given another menu that will appear when you select that cascade entry from the menubar.